# Add points from Google Maps to ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, google-maps, kml

I would like to export the points I added to Google Maps, in a designated list, so I can use them in ArcGIS. I can't find a solution so far.

I added the points to a list on Google Maps while in the field, and would now like to convert the points to KML and export them to use in ArcMap.

Comment: What's "a list on google maps"? How did you add the points? Screenshots might help.

Comment: Adding KML to ArcMap should be straightforward so where you are stuck seems to be with exporting KML from Google Maps. I think you should focus your question on that.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "Google Maps list", do you mean your lists of saved places, which  you can get to through the "Your Places" option in the main menu at https://maps.google.com?  If so, you should be able to export the contents of those lists to a GeoJSON file using Google's "takeout" data export tool.  Takeout is primarily for backing up or transferring your account data, but can sometimes be useful for exporting things like this that don't have an export option in the product itself.  If you go to https://takeout.google.com, and select just the "Maps (your places)" option, you'll see that you can export your saved places and lists.  Once you get the GeoJSON file, you should be able to import that into most GIS software packages.

Alternatively, if you're talking about a list of places created in Google My Maps, then that's even simpler, since you should be able to export that as a KML file, and then import that into your GIS software.  When you export KML from My Maps for use in other software, make sure to NOT select the option to "Keep data up to date with network link KML", since that will only provide a KML file that points to the My Map, and does not actually contain the data.  And DO select the option to "Export as KML instead of KMZ.", so that you don't have to unzip the KMZ.